Getting "semantic error TS2339: Property 'hgetall' does not exist on type 'Redis'" when creating a package with ioredis and tsdx
I used npx tsdx to create a basic module.  I then added ioredis package. When I use methods like hgetall or del in the package I get this typescript error
(typescript) Error: /sample/redis-package/src/records.ts(27,43): semantic error TS2339: Property 'hgetall' does not exist on type 'Redis'.
Error: /sample/redis-package/src/records.ts(27,43): semantic error TS2339: Property 'hgetall' does not exist on type 'Redis'.
    at error (/sample/redis-package/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/node-entry.js:5400:30)
    at throwPluginError (/sample/redis-package/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/node-entry.js:11878:12)
    at Object.error (/sample/redis-package/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/node-entry.js:12912:24)
    at Object.error (/sample/redis-package/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/node-entry.js:12081:38)
    at RollupContext.error (/sample/redis-package/node_modules/tsdx/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/dist/rollup-plugin-typescript2.cjs.js:17237:30)
    at /sample/redis-package/node_modules/tsdx/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/dist/rollup-plugin-typescript2.cjs.js:25033:23
    at arrayEach (/sample/redis-package/node_modules/tsdx/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/dist/rollup-plugin-typescript2.cjs.js:545:11)
    at Function.forEach (/sample/redis-package/node_modules/tsdx/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/dist/rollup-plugin-typescript2.cjs.js:9397:14)
    at printDiagnostics (/sample/redis-package/node_modules/tsdx/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/dist/rollup-plugin-typescript2.cjs.js:25006:12)
    at Object.transform (/sample/redis-package/node_modules/tsdx/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/dist/rollup-plugin-typescript2.cjs.js:29277:17)
    at /sample/redis-package/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/node-entry.js:13117:25
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:447:9)

my tsconfig.json
{
  "include": ["src", "types"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "importHelpers": true,
    // output .d.ts declaration files for consumers
    "declaration": true,
    // output .js.map sourcemap files for consumers
    "sourceMap": true,
    // match output dir to input dir. e.g. dist/index instead of dist/src/index
    "rootDir": "./src",
    // stricter type-checking for stronger correctness. Recommended by TS
    "strict": true,
    // linter checks for common issues
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    // noUnused* overlap with @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars, can disable if duplicative
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    // use Node's module resolution algorithm, instead of the legacy TS one
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    // transpile JSX to React.createElement
    //"jsx": "react",
    // interop between ESM and CJS modules. Recommended by TS
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    // significant perf increase by skipping checking .d.ts files, particularly those in node_modules. Recommended by TS
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    // error out if import and file system have a casing mismatch. Recommended by TS
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    // `tsdx build` ignores this option, but it is commonly used when type-checking separately with `tsc`
    "noEmit": true,
  }
}

my packages.json
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsdx watch",
    "build": "tsdx build",
    "test": "tsdx test",
    "lint": "tsdx lint",
    "prepare": "tsdx build",
    "size": "size-limit",
    "analyze": "size-limit --why"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {},
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "tsdx lint"
    }
  },
  "prettier": {
    "printWidth": 80,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "es5"
  },
  "name": "redis-package",
  "author": "sample",
  "module": "dist/redis-package.esm.js",
  "size-limit": [
    {
      "path": "dist/redis-package.cjs.production.min.js",
      "limit": "10 KB"
    },
    {
      "path": "dist/redis-package.esm.js",
      "limit": "10 KB"
    }
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@size-limit/preset-small-lib": "^11.1.4",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "size-limit": "^11.1.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsdx": "^0.14.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ioredis": "^5.4.1"
  }
}


making a call to redis hgetall or del and more gets the typescript error. Sample code
try {
    const redis = getRedis();
    const result = await redis.hgetall(key);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`unable to find specified record for key ${key}`, {
      cause: error,
    });
  }

I am not sure why typescript is failing when those methods or commands exist on ioredis.
